# How to avoid from special characters in flash messages

Tags: laravel, special-characters, flash-message

I have a flash message when i changed my password but it shows me some ?? sign in my message i dont know why its showing.

My Code where i am displaying this message

```
             $('#password_change_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var saveThis = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/changepassword",
            data: $(saveThis).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $(".success-messages").text("Heslo bylo úspešne zmeneno").fadeIn();
                $('#password_change_form').trigger("reset");


            },
```

you can see the success message ("Heslo bylo úspešne zmeneno")
and i have also attached the screen shot its looking like.[image: this is the screen shot where i am having ??]

I am having ?? in my message please you can see in the image i dont want to show this characters.

Your help needs here

Comment: It seems you are facing with encoding issue. Did you make you text editor and the html (with meta tag) in the same encoding, e.g. utf-8?

Comment: yes i did make but it still the same issue i have also other wording in this language in same page its showing correctly but issue is only in this message

Comment: Can you confirm that it is correctly displayed when you look at the source code of the page?

Comment: no its not displaying correctly when i see source code but others are displaying well in source code except this ... what can be the issue?

Comment: Maybe, your text editor supports multiple encodings and it shows the characters in correct way. Can you rewrite the text shown incorrectly as you did for the others? (For example, you typed some texts and copied and pasted others)

Comment: when re-write its showing correctly ...

Comment: Okay, I am answering the question based on the solution in discussion

Answer (score 1):

As of the comments, it is an encoding issue. Make all the texts in the same encoding. Sometimes, copied-pasted texts can remain in different encoding than you have supposed to.

So,

- Check the source code of the web page.
- Re-write the "not correctly displayed" texts as the ones correctly displayed.